# Can I use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem in my bots?

Tags: botframework, bots

Can I use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem like this?
Does these codes cause some error when many people using my bot at the same time?

> ```
>     public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
>     {
>         if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
>         {
>             HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(c => DoBotTaskAsync(activity));
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             await Task.Run(() => DoBotTaskAsync(activity));
>         }
>         var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
>         return response;
>     }
> private async Task DoBotTaskAsync(Activity activity)
> {
>     if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
>     {
>         await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         HandleSystemMessage(activity);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Do you host your bot application on Azure web app?

Comment: Yes. I host it on Azure web app, and use WebChat. Some times my bot throw 'stack is empty' exception but not alaways so I think maybe something wrong in my codes.

Comment: Exception is thrown sometimes (Not always) in this case: People A use my bot, and after about one hour when People B use it, the first message goes wrong, but input the same message again it will be OK.

Comment: `the first message goes wrong, but input the same message again it will be OK` Does it throw 'stack is empty' exception when send the first message?

Comment: Yes. 'Stack is empty' is thrown. I wrote this issuse, but the error is not always shown so I closed it.  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4406

Comment: By the way, I use TableStorage Now. Before Mar.31, I used default States API and it worked well.  My bot's codes are the same except TableStorage is 'Use' or 'Not Use'.

Comment: @FeiHan Hello, any update for my question, please? Thank you!